# calculating maximum moving average for more than 18 hours of ozone value

Tags: r, moving-average

I'm trying to calculate the maximum moving average for ozone. I Wrote this code. I want to write a code that calculates moving average when I have more than 18 hours of ozone values in a day. How can I write it?
The code that I wrote, is true or not?

```
Data= data.frame(Date=rep(seq.Date(as.Date("2013-03-21"),by=1, length.out = 2),each=24),
Time=c(0:23),
               o3= (c(1:43,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)))

Unique_DATE = na.omit( unique( Data[,1] ) ) 

COUNT = c()
for( i in 1:length( Unique_DATE ) ){
  
  
  COUNT[i] = 24-sum( is.na( Data[ Data[,1] == Unique_DATE[i] , 3 ] ) )
  
}

mean(COUNT>=18)


library( forecast )

MAX_MOVING_AVERAGE = c()


for( i in 1:length( Unique_DATE ) ){
  
  
  MAX_MOVING_AVERAGE[i] = 
    max(  ma(   Data[ Data[,1] == Unique_DATE[i] , 3 ] 
                , order=8 ) , na.rm = TRUE )
  
  
}


MAX_MA=data.frame( Unique_DATE , MAX_MOVING_AVERAGE  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `dplyr` and reduce the code to something much smaller.

```
Data <- data.frame(Date=rep(seq.Date(as.Date("2013-03-21"),by=1, 
                   length.out = 3),each=24),
                   Time=c(0:23),
                   o3= 
     (c(1:43,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1:12,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)))

library(forecast)
library(dplyr)
summary_all <-
    Data %>% 
    dplyr::group_by(Date) %>% 
    dplyr::summarize(max_ma=max(ma(o3, order=8), na.rm=T), 
                     count=sum(!is.na(o3)))

summary <- summary_all %>% dplyr::filter(count >= 18)

summary
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  Date       max_ma count
  <date>      <dbl> <int>
1 2013-03-21     20    24
2 2013-03-22     39    19
```

I added another day of data with fewer than 18 data points in a day to illustrate how you can count the number and then filter out those with insufficient numbers.